# Move email to folder if more than one partial strings found in email subject

Tags: python, email, outlook

1. I have a list containing Folder Names at the Outlook level ['fried chicken'; "boiled pasta"; "baked potatoes"], folders exist and are empty.
   The elements are strings that are combinations of two words example "fried chicken".
2. I search the Inbox and if the `message.subject` matches one of the elements in the list move that email to the folder.
   Example: Email subject is "How fried is the chicken" or "I like my potatoes to be baked". It is not string in string exactly so my `message.Move` call doesn't find anything relevant.

Below is the "code".

```
alerts_folder = root_folder.Folders[folder_name_selected]
messages = alerts_folder.Items
z=messages.Count
message = messages.GetLast()
for message in list(messages):
    name = str(message.subject).lower()
    
`   #message = messages.GetPrevious()
    for y in top5:
        if all(x in name for x in y.split()):
            #print(str(name))
            #print("Email " + name + " goes into folder " + alerts_folder[y])
            name_of_selected_folder = str(y)
            final_destination = alerts_folder.Folders[name_of_selected_folder]
            #print("Email " + name + " goes into folder " + name_of_selected_folder)
            message.Move(final_destination)
            #message.Move(name_of_selected_folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for message in messages:
    name = str(message.subject)
    message = messages.GetPrevious()
    for y in list:
        if any(x in name for x in y.split()):
            print(str(name))
            #print("Email " + name + " goes into folder " + alerts_folder[list])
            message.Move(alerts_folder.Folders[list])
```

The code above firstly iterates over list and then splits every element in a list (as each element is a string of two words).

Comment: THank you for help. And any idea how to make it to consider also Upper and lower case? Example Email subject contains: "Fried free chicken" and "fried Chicken" to take both into consideration.

Comment: You would have to make everything either lower or uppercase. So `x.lower()` and `name.lower()`

Comment: Super it works. and before I close the thread I have one more thing if I may ask:
The message.Move(alerts_folder.Folders[name_of_selected_folder]) is returning AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Move' .
As if the message is None, but I declared it message = alerts_folder.Items[name]

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `messages.GetPrevious()` ? It might represent the problem you are having, I don't recall dict having that method, unless you're using some external library

Comment: If you could add some more code to your initial question to show how you define messages and everything else that might be relevant, it would be more helpful

Comment: `alerts_folder = root_folder.Folders[folder_name_selected]
messages = alerts_folder.Items
z=messages.Count
message = messages.GetLast()
for message in list(messages):
    name = str(message.subject).lower()
    
    #print(type(message))
    #message = messages.GetPrevious()
    for y in top5:
        if all(x in name for x in y.split()):

            name_of_selected_folder = str(y)
            final_destination = alerts_folder.Folders[name_of_selected_folder]
            message.Move(final_destination)`

Comment: How do you define `root_folder` ?

Comment: `outlook = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application').GetNamespace("MAPI")
substring = "@mailbox.com"
substring_negative = "Public Folders"

for folder in outlook.Folders:
    #print(folder)
    if substring in str(folder):
        if not substring_negative in str(folder):
            email_box=str(folder)

folder_names = []
email_subject = []
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(email_box)`

Comment: Instead of `message = messages.GetLast` try `messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)` and continue to comment out the `getPrevious()` bit

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the fact that *x* in `if any(x in name for x in list)` is the entire folder name.

If you're message subject is "fried chicken tasty" the code will match for the folder "fried chicken" but not for "fried  chicken".

You can try with this code:

```
subject = "How fried is the chicken"
folders = ['fried chicken', 'boiled pasta', 'baked potatoes']
for folder in folders:
      keywords = folder.split()
      any(keyword in subject for keyword in keywords)
```

output will be:

```
True
False
False
```

note that this will work also for a partial subject matching like:

```
subject2 = "chicken tasty"
```

that is it will return true if only a folder keyword is in the subject string.

consider using `all()` function istead of `any()` to require all the keywords in folder names to be in the subject

```
for folder in folders:
    keywords = folder.split()
    all(keyword in subject for keyword in keywords)
```